# Converting between physical pixels and CSS pixels

Tags: css

Mozilla's documentation from [elementFromPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM:document.elementFromPoint) explains that the coordinates are not in physical pixels, but "CSS pixels". Exactly what are CSS pixels? I was under the impression that a pixel in CSS was the same as the physical pixel.

If this is not the case, how does one convert between physical and CSS pixels?

Comment: OK, so it seems like the problem was that the page I was testing with had a custom zoom level, which was screwing up the computation. I was not aware that zooming is per-page. Thanks for your help, everyone.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A pixel is a physical screen pixel as far as any web page can reasonably concern itself.

The wording ‘CSS pixel’ refers to a pixel as [defined in CSS 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#x39)

> the whole number of device pixels that best approximates the reference pixel. It is recommended that the reference pixel be the visual angle of one pixel on a device with a pixel density of 96dpi and a distance from the reader of an arm's length. For a nominal arm's length of 28 inches, the visual angle is therefore about 0.0213 degrees.

What this is saying is that a CSS pixel is a device pixel for the normal, simple screen cases. However, for specialist super-high-res screens where the OS scales up its normal dimensions by two, a CSS pixel may be two device pixels wide.

We now also have a ‘zoom’ feature in most browsers, which will naturally change the size of the CSS pixel (along with all other units) so it doesn't match a device pixel.

Comment: Is this just a way of keeping CSS pixels proportional with the rest of the HTML site. For example, if I had a DIV with a width of 350 pixels it wouldn't (not likely) take up half the width of a modern browser. If I put the same file into a tablet/phone browser, the same result would persists? Despite physical pixels meaning it could even be wider than the device, the CSS pixels allows this "proportioning" to take place?

Comment: In the last line of your answer, you mean to say it zooms to that css pixel will match to physical pixel?

Answer (score 5):

As I'm sure you know, [CSS provides a number of different units for representing length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/length). Some are based on physical, real-world measurements (inches, millimeters, points) while others are relative to something else (em width, percentage).

But pixels are neither of these. Originally, they were (as you assumed) merely the smallest addressable dot on a user's screen. However, this is problematic for a number of reasons:

- The renderer may actually be using sub-pixel positioning to avoid rounding errors.
- The output device may not *have* pixels - a ten-dot font on a 600dpi printer is unlikely to reflect what the designer actually wanted.
- Similar to printing, pages designed for common, low-resolution displays (72-96dpi) may be unreadable on high-resolution displays.
- Modern browsers offer powerful tools to scale / magnify pages.

And so CSS pixels are a useful abstraction: they have well-defined relations to other measurements (at least, within a given browser...) and thus page designers can rely on the results looking reasonably close to their designs even when the browser must change the relationship to actual, device pixels.

To answer your second question, you *don't* convert between physical and CSS pixels. That would defeat the whole point by destroying [an abstraction that the renderer needs in order to operate properly](http://weblogs.mozillazine.org/roc/archives/2008/10/hating_pixels.html). Gecko does provide [a way](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIDOMWindowUtils) to determine the relationship, but only to chrome scripts - normal web pages should remain blissfully unaware...

#### Further reading: [Units Patch Landed](http://weblogs.mozillazine.org/roc/archives/2007/02/units_patch_lan.html)

Answer (score 5):

Conversion can be done with `window.devicePixelRatio;` now supported by all major browsers

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio

Answer (score 3):

In most cases, yes, CSS pixels are the same as physical pixels.  According to the [CSS 2.1 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#length-units):

> Pixel units are relative to the resolution of the viewing device, i.e., most often a computer display. If the pixel density of the output device is very different from that of a typical computer display, the user agent should rescale pixel values.

Typically, 1 pixel on the device will be the same as 1 pixel in CSS.  On a device with a very high pixel density, you might find that its CSS pixel size is actually 2 physical pixels wide, but I don't know of any devices that do so.  Not even the iPhone 4, with its Retina Display, will adjust its CSS pixel size.

As pointed out by Shog9, most browsers' zoom features will adjust the scale of the pixels being displayed, but in most cases, CSS pixels will be the same as the physical device.

Comment: Uh... if your browser supports a "zoom" feature, you can disprove that last statement rather quickly...

Comment: @Shog9 - Thanks for pointing that out.  To be fair, some older browsers only scale text instead of the entire page, but yes, that would change the scale.

Comment: Firefox'll still do that if you want... (option under the view menu).