# How can i specify CSS Pixels

Tags: css, pixel

I am developing a mobile web application for our client and the web designer send a detailed specification about the screen design in all his specification he mentioned the height and width in "css pixels" like `logo is positioned 116 css pixels from the top`

so what is this CSS pixels and how can i specify this in my css please help

Regards

Denny

Comment: What do you think the unit `px` in css stands for?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588983/converting-between-physical-pixels-and-css-pixels

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="logo">
    <img src="http://olea.org/ilustraciones/fedora-logo-icon.png">
</div>
```

---

```
.logo {
    margin-top:116px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k6Nmt/1/

Answer (score 0):

CSS (Cascading Style Sheets) is a language for website that declares a style. Pixel is a unit for declaring width, height and etc. So I believe your client just used CSS term incorrectly.
You can review some basics of CSS in here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/

Comment: so what is the difference between pixels and "CSS Pixels"

Comment: There is no such "CSS Pixel". CSS term was used incorectly. Pixel is a measurement, while CSS is a name of programming language.

Comment: [w3fools](http://w3fools.com) There're many better up-to-date website, like [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/)