# Javascript reporting wrong window size

Tags: javascript, mobile

I am currently coding a web page for personal use. Also for the sake of it I am trying to make a fluid design. To achieve this I try to figure out stuff about the client window in order to change the placement of some of the stuff in the page. But I have come accross the following problem. It seems that `window.innerWidth` is.. wrong.

On my desktop pc it returns the value of 1366 (when the window is maximised) which is slightly
wrong since it counts the scrollbar width. I can fix this by using `document.documentElement.clientWidth` which does not take into account the scrollbar

On the mobile front the thing is even worse `window.innerWidth` is reporting a value of 360
both on a nexus 5 and an iphone 4s that I have on my disposal for testing. This is not mitigated by the use of `document.documentElement.clientWidth`. Is there a way to reliably know the window width of the browser viewing my page?

Comment: What? How is that wrong? Of course it factors in the pixel-ratio, but that is normal. It's talking about CSS pixels here. It will also be affected by zoom on desktop browsers.

Comment: @Dude any reading material on CSS pixels? I really dont know what it is. (I am not really a web developer so sorry if the question is a bit foolish)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588983/converting-between-physical-pixels-and-css-pixels

Comment: I use `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />`, so the CSS pixels should be equal to physical pixels. But the window `window.innerWidth` reports far less pixels than the screen actual resolution.

Comment: Did you read the entire answer? "What this is saying is that a CSS pixel is a device pixel for the normal, simple screen cases. However, for specialist super-high-res screens where the OS scales up its normal dimensions by two, a CSS pixel may be two device pixels wide." BTW, disabling zoom is _extremely_ annoying.